# Which is the difference between Celledited and TargetUpdated in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I wanted to handle when a value in a cell is modify, and I would like to do it with MVVM, so I would like to know when the value of a cell is changed in a datagrid, be notify to the view model and do something according the new value. The cell is just a text cell.

I am reading about CellEdited and TargetUpdated, but I don't see really which is the difference. It seems both notify when the value is changed, but I don't know when it is better to use one and when the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM you would handle the change of the value in the setter of the source property whose value is displayed in the cell.

For example, given a column that is defined like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Header..." />
```

...you would handle the change in the setter of the `Value` property of your data object. There should be no reason to involve any events in the view.

Comment: Yes, this was my first idea but I have a doubt. if I have for example 5 rows, I have 5 objects that are the source of each row. So to intercept the change of value in the property, should I subcribe to the event of each object, si I should to subcribe to 5 events?

Comment: The same property will be set for all objects, won't it?